# Given a continuous function determine the topology on R.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

[image]

[image]

I have shown that every pre-image of an element in the basis of the order topology is some kind of interval i.e. $[a,b],[a,b),(a,b),(a,b],[a,\infty)$ etc. But this does not give a general description of the topology on R

Comment: Hint: $\{a\}\in\mathcal T'$ for every $a\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Wojowu I see $f^{-1}(((a,b),(a,c)))=\{a\}$,where $b<c$. therefore every subset is open.